# How can I make UI list items disabled

Tags: javascript

This is my list:

```
<ul class="documents">
       <li class="list_title"><div class="Srequired">NEW</div></li>
       <li class="doc_price>1</li>
       <li class="doc_price>2</li>
       <li class="list_title dark_green"><div class="Sother">OLD</div></li>
       <li class="doc_choice dark_green">3</li>
       <li class="doc_choice dark_green">4</li>
       <li class="doc_price">No Doc</li>
</ul>
```

I want the items on the list to be disabled (the user won't be able to select) until this filed has a value:

```
<input type="text" class="Sloan_input rr" id="Sloan_input" placeholder="Enter Order" />
```

I saw a few related questions but couldn't find a solution, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _the user won't be able to select_ , `ul` isn't a selectable element...

Comment: How is a user able to select from a UL? Maybe we need to know what code you are using what makes it selectable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There s no disabled attribute for `li` and `ul`. Use css property to disable it.Also `ul` and `li` are not selectable

```js
document.getElementById("Sloan_input").addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (this.value !== "") {
    document.getElementsByClassName('documents')[0].classList.remove('disableEle')

  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('documents')[0].classList.add('disableEle')
  }
})
```

```css
.disableEle {
  pointer-events: null;
  cursor: no-drop
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="Sloan_input rr" id="Sloan_input" placeholder="Enter Order" />
<ul class="documents disableEle">
  <li class="list_title">
    <div class="Srequired">NEW</div>
  </li>
  <li class="doc_price">1</li>
  <li class=" doc_price">2</li>
  <li class=" list_title dark_green ">
    <div class="Sother ">OLD</div>
  </li>
  <li class="doc_choice dark_green ">3</li>
  <li class="doc_choice dark_green ">4</li>
  <li class="doc_price ">No Doc</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You May try for this:)

In HTML part:

```
<input type="text" class="Sloan_input rr" id="Sloan_input" placeholder="Enter Order" />
<ul id="documents">
       <li class="list_title"><div class="Srequired">NEW</div></li>
       <li class="doc_price>1</li>
       <li class="doc_price>2</li>
       <li class="list_title dark_green"><div class="Sother">OLD</div></li>
       <li class="doc_choice dark_green">3</li>
       <li class="doc_choice dark_green">4</li>
       <li class="doc_price">No Doc</li>
</ul>
```

In js Part:

```
$("#Sloan_input").keyup(function(e) {
    //Prevent <button>'s default action
    e.preventDefault();

    //toggle all the <li> elements selectable-ness
    $("#documents> li").toggleClass("unselectable");

});
```

In CSS part:

```
.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook a EventListener to your `<input/>` element. 
If the `<input/>` it's value changes, change the state of the `li` items.